# Generate invoice and shipping automatically on order status update to "processing"

Tags: shipping, extensions, invoice

If order-status is changed to "processing" the system should auto-generate invoice, shipping AND send the default mails for that to the customer!

Does anybody know an extension that can do that for Magento 1.0.7.2?

Thx in forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great one:

http://www.vianetz.com/de/magento-module/automaticinvoice.html/

It is called automaticinvoice but also generates the shipment automatically and has a lot more features.

As a big plus: Its guaranteed to work with for example PayOne, Firegento, GermanSetup, aso ...